# QT5 не вызывается dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)

Tags: qt, qt5, drag-n-drop

в моей программе используется перемещение айтемов между QListWidget'ами.
сам процесс как я понял не требует кода и достаточно настроить объекты в UI.
но мне нужно проводить операцию с перенесенными айтемами, для этого как я понял мне нужно переопределить функцию **dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);**

собственно что я и сделал, заодно переопределив еще парочку

```
protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
```

проблема в том что ни одна из них никогда не вызывается.
что я сделал не так?

и еще наблюдаю странную работу переноса объектов: мне по задаче нужно переносить объекты пачками а не по одному. Для этого я выставил всем виджетам параметр selectionMode в MultiSelection, и кликаю по нужным с зажатым crl. затем когда я выбрал те что нужно перенести я кликаю по любому из выбранных и переношу их в другой виджет, так вот когда я кликаю   по объекту какой уже выбран  выбор с него почему то снимается.

а если же я начну перемещение сразу же после клика по последнему не отпуская больше мышь объекты скопируются а не переместятся

хотя все прекрасно работает если выбирать объекты просто кликая мышкой, без нажатия crl, правда опять же мне нужно переносить объекты сразу же после клика по последнему

ищу варианты чтоб это пофиксить.

Comment: попробуйте использоваться ExtendedSelection. По поводу копирования объектов, попробуйте изменить значения свойства defaultDropAction

Comment: ExtendedSelection ничего не дал кроме как запретил выбирать пачки мышкой. и да я забыл упомянуть что у всех виджетов defaultDropAction установлен в MoveAction

Comment: Уточните, вы пытаетесь сделать dnd между несколькими виджетами, или внутри одного?

Comment: несколькими qlistwidget

Comment: мне нужно обновить перемещенную запись в базе.

Comment: Я в подобной ситуации переопределял mousePressEvent и mouseMoveEvent как показано тут http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html. Чтобы при начале драга не снималось выделение с айтема, за который начали тащить, в начале драга проверяю, входит ли itemAt(dragStartPosition) в список выбранных айтемов, если нет - значит его исключило при нажатии и его надо добавить обратно

Comment: Bearded Beaver, кошмар какой то ))

Comment: скажите кто-нибудь что не так с оверрайдом?

Comment: так я кажется понял, мне нужно переопределить сам класс qlistwidget и создать тем самым свой. мне их потом только программно в форму вставлять?

Comment: Нет, можно добавить QListWidget в дизайнере, на него пкм, promote to и преобразовать в виджет-наследник

Comment: Bearded Beaver, ясно понятно. это мне подходит

Comment: осталось только понять как получить текст дропнутого объекта

Comment: Все параметры таскаемых объектов помещаются в mimeData->data в виде QByteArray

Comment: Да я вкурсе, но пока не смог найти как достать текст. пробовал event->mimeData()->data("text/plain"); и по другому. выдает всегда пустую строку